# Angular Datatables: rowCallback & Serverside Angular does not work together

Tags: angular, datatables

Hello I have been trying to get row click event to work with serve side ajax call. The problem is I cannot get the rowCallback function to work at all. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

I am trying to combine the following two example together. Which I think should be a simple task. I have searched for solutions online and I have no run into anyone else that ran into same problem as I have. I am currently new with Angular so I am trying to learn how to create a Angular Web Application.

Example:
http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way
http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/row-click-event

```js
  someClickHandler(info) {
    this.message = info.product;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //other code
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      responsive: true,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback, settings) => {
        this.http
          .post<DataTablesResponse>(
            'placeholder',
            dataTablesParameters, httpOptions
          ).subscribe(resp => {
            this.filteredData = resp.data;
            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
              recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
              data: [],
            });
          });
      },
      columns: [{ data: 'product' }, { data: 'name' }, { data: 'vendor' }],
      rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
        const self = this;
        // Unbind first in order to avoid any duplicate handler
        // (see https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/87)
        $('td', row).unbind('click');
        $('td', row).bind('click', () => {
          self.someClickHandler(data);
        });
        return row;
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Hi Kenneth Did you get the first example working before you moved onto the second example?

Comment: Yes. I got both example working separately but when I combine them they do not work together. I also have an update when I set data: resp.data in callback. Then the datatable is rendered with rowCallback functionality.

That would mean I cannot use manually write html buttons for each row in html. 

```html Example: <td><button type="button" id="update" class="btn btn-success" (click)="event">Update</button></td>```

Comment: @KennethKon Now working?

Comment: @KennethKon have you got this working?

Comment: Hi all. Sorry for the late reply. I did not find a solution to this problem and have moved on. At the moment I am not working on Angular so I will not encounter this issue for now.